# How does one handle a backspace event with JavaScript on an empty HTML input?

Tags: javascript, keypress, dom-events, html-input, backspace

How is it possible to and what is best practice for listening and handling an event using Javascript which shall be triggered by pressing backspace on an `<input type="text" />` which also is triggered when the inputs value is empty and was **empty before the event**?

Comment: Have you tried Googling this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you like this way? Only triggers if you press backspace inside the input... take a look!(Using Jquery)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keydown','input[type="text"]',function(e){

        if(event.keyCode == 8){
            alert('backspace');
        }

        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

And this code triggers if the input is empty

```
    if($('#input').val() == ''){
        alert('input empty');
    }
```